# TriggerEventHandler in unit testing angular 4

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I had an element

```
<button class="next-btn" (mouseup)="someMethod()">Next</button>
```

I want to simulate mouseup event in testing and i do this

```
const nextBtnElem = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
const elem = nextBtnElem.getElementsByTagName('button')[1]
elem.triggerEventHandler('mouseup', null);
```

it doesn't work, but if i change it like this

```
const nextBtnElem = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.next-btn');
nextBtnElem.triggerEventHandler('mouseup', null);
```

Now its working. I can't understand why first optional doesn't work?

Comment: const elem = nextBtn.getElementsByTagName('button')[1] what is `nextBtn`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`triggerEventHandler` is a function that exists on Angular's `DebugElement`. In your first code snippet you are calling `triggerEventHandler` on a DOM object, that does not provide this functionality. On DOM objects you could use [dispatchEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) but you must call `fixture.detectChanges();` between triggering your event and your assertions then.